# Compare local files with files in different server c#

Tags: c#, settings

I´m creating a WPF project for compare local files agains files on a different server. I have the code for compare files. I´m using linQ for compare last Date Write, size and name. I did the test for that using settings on a .config file.
But I dónt know how to include the server address in the config file for compare that values.
Help please and thanks in advance

Comment: Bit confusing. How does your server address looks like?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, I just know that I should tocompare files of the local solution vs the archives of the solutiondevelopment server for to know which is the latest version and upload the missing changes, I assume that the address looks something like HTTP /: SERVER / SolutionName. But that´s part of my question I don´t know how to include that address.